# takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to save the variable via json, but instead it gives me the following error: with open ("File.json", "w") as file:
TypeError: open() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

```
file_name = ""
def save():
    global file_name
    with open("Filen.json", "w") as file:
        json.dumps(file_name, file)
def open():
    global file_name
    if file_name == "":
        file_name = tfd.askopenfilename()
        os.startfile(file_name)
    else:
        os.startfile(file_name)
    save()
    if btn1["text"] == "":
        btn1["text"] = file_name
```

Comment: You have defined open as a function which takes no positional arguments. Change the name of that function if you want to use the built in function or include the arguments in its definition.

Comment: @ChrisOram Thank you, everything works